# How to migrate ghost blog on local machine to digital ocean web server?

Tags: nginx, migration, hosting, digital-ocean, ghost-blog

I am following this tutorial here [(How To Host Ghost with Nginx on DigitalOcean)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-ghost-with-nginx-on-digitalocean)  but I am stuck on the step to copy my local files over to my Digital Ocean web server. I am pretty confused as to whether or not I have to FTP or something, or whether I have to create another droplet/VPS and install ghost on there, and then copy everything from my local machine to the new VPS instance.

Ideally, I would like to just be able to edit my local blog and deploy straight from there, but it seems very difficult.

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Copying my local ghost blog files to my server!

Comment: Do you know how to ssh into a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update: this imported my posts, but not the theme I installed or the images.  I guess you could reinstall the theme at digitalocean and ssh the images any custom css you did to the theme?

On your Mac go to127.0.0.1:2368/ghost/debug and export. Then go to the your Digital Ocean ipaddress/ghost/debug and import.

https://ghost.org/forum/installation/3067-migrating-from-a-local-ghost-blog-on-mac-to-digital-ocean/

---

original post:
Copying the contents folder from local to digital ocean did not work for me. I copied my entire contents folder from local to digitalocean and renamed the existing digitalocean content folder.  This breaks the blog.  I am searching now for a migration how to.  I will update this if I find the answer.

Comment: so all I did was just SSH in and manually copy my files over and then restart the server. its annoying that this is the way to do it, but whatever, as long as it is updated for each post and i can get the personalized theming i want, i'll be fine. it would really be nice if i could just deploy from my local copy though.

Answer (score -1):

This information should help you:

- [How To Use SSH Keys with PuTTY on DigitalOcean Droplets](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-digitalocean-droplets-windows-users)
- [How To
  Use Filezilla to Transfer and Manage Files Securely on your VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-filezilla-to-transfer-and-manage-files-securely-on-your-vps)